# Access Violation Exception while calling an ActiveX DLL

Tags: vb.net, activex, visual-foxpro

I have created an ActiveX DLL which contains a class two properties and a method.I am using this DLL as a wrapper to another Visual Foxpro 6 dll which referes internally.In short this dll is used to communicate between VB.NET and Visual Foxpro using Activex Dll.I am able to register dll in client machine.But after creating an object,if I try to access member properties or methods it is throwing an exception

> AccessViolationException was unhandled.Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

[Activex DLL Reference Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUASv.jpg)

Comment: Try changing the Platform for Build from Any CPU to x86.

Comment: i am in a 64 bit windows 7 premium machine.

but when i compiled the project i changed the platform to x86 and .net framework 4  ,but still the error is there